# Find the first time a value repeats at least n consecutive times, by group

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2), Val = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

For each id, I'd like to find the first time when the value TRUE repeats at least twice in a row. For id = 1, this occurs at the second value. For id = 2, this occurs at the 5th value.

I have tried playing around with cumsum, and also rle, but the latter doesn't seem to work by group in the "dplyr" way.

Comment: What would you like returned? An example of your desired result might help.

Answer (score 0):

One way with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                        2, 2, 2), Val = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                          FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, idx:= rowid(id)]
df[, size:= .N, rleid(id, Val)]
result <- df[size>=2 & Val, .(first= idx[1]), id]
```

Comment: "The first time when the value TRUE repeats at least twice" would translate to `==2` and not `>=2`

Comment: Well no. Repeats twice translates to ==2, "At least" to >=2

Comment: "the first time at least twice" is twice

Comment: I see, but the size here refers to the size of the repeat. the idx[1] means the first time